# create a menu hierarchy bootstraps with PHP and mysql

Tags: mysql, oop, hierarchy, codeigniter-3

sorry for my bad english 
i have a table menu : 
[here is my table menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOjkU.png)

so I want to ask, how the process of making code based on the data in the table ..
or maybe anyone has any reference in this regard?

This is the code I tried but still failed

```
public function all_tree()
    {
        $nodes = $this->db->get('alus_menu_group')->result();
        return $this->getChildren($nodes, 0, 0);
    }

public function getChildren($nodes ,$pid = 0, $depth = 0)
   {
      $tree = array();

      foreach($nodes as $node) {

         if ($node->menu_parent == $pid) {

            if($depth == 0)
            {
               if(!$this->getChildren1($nodes, $node->menu_id, ($depth + 1)))
               {
                  $hasil = "<li class='dropdown'>
                      <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>".$node->menu_nama."</a>
                      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
                  $hasil .= $this->getChildren($nodes, $node->menu_id, ($depth + 1));

               }else
               {
                  $hasil = "<li><a href=".base_url().$node->menu_uri." target=".$node->menu_target.">".$node->menu_nama."</a></li>";      
               }
            }
            if($depth == 1)
            {
               if(!$this->getChildren1($nodes, $node->menu_id, ($depth + 1)))
               {
                  $hasil = "<li class='dropdown-submenu'>
                      <a href='#'>".$node->menu_nama."</a>
                      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
                  $hasil .= $this->getChildren($nodes, $node->menu_id, ($depth + 1));

               }else
               {
                  $hasil = "<li><a href=".base_url().$node->menu_uri." target=".$node->menu_target.">".$node->menu_nama."</a></li></ul></li>";      

               }

            }if ($depth == 2) 
            {
               $hasil = "<li><a href=".base_url().$node->menu_uri." target=".$node->menu_target.">".$node->menu_nama."2</a></li></ul></li></ul></li>";   

            }
            $tree[]   = $hasil;
         }

      }
      return $tree;
   }
    public function view()
{
$data['tree'] = $this->all_tree();
$this->load->view('index.php',$data);
}
```

then in view.php im doing foreach . 
someone can help ? thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is this -> http://pastebin.com/GAFvSew4 thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you.

[Link from code.tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-drop-down-nav-menu-with-html5-css3-and-jquery--net-12176)

You just need to make dynamic data based on above link's html.

Hope this may help you !!